# Homeomorphism of two product spaces

Tags: general-topology

Given $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ topological spaces such that $X_1\cong Y_1$  and $X_2\cong Y_2$ how to prove $X_1\times X_2\cong Y_1\times Y_2$. I'm interested in the particular case $X_1=X_2=[0,1]$, $Y_1=[0,b]$ and $Y_2=[0,e]$ with $b,e\in R$ to show area is not a topological property.

Comment: In particular case, $\varphi : (x,y) \mapsto (x,\frac{ey}b)$, and the most important condition : $e,b\ne0$

Comment: You can't come up with any functions $X_1 \times X_2 \to Y_1 \times Y_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h_1: X_1 \to Y_1$ is a homeomorphism (we know it exists) and $h_2: X_2 \to Y_2$ as well, show that $H: X_1 \times X_2 \to Y_1 \times Y_2$ given by $H(x,x')=(h_1(x),h_2(x'))$ is also a homeomorphism.

Use e.g. that a map $f:Z \to X \times Y$ is continuous iff $\pi_X \circ f$ and $\pi_Y \circ f$ is continuous, where $\pi_X,\pi_Y$ are the standard projection maps...